# cout causing access violation in VC++ 10

Tags: c++, visual-c++, access-violation, cout

apologies, I'm relatively new at C++, so I'm debugging this code, which is giving me an access violation the third time cout << is called (right after load_array returns):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define FILENAME "H:\\test.preisach"
#define ROWS 32760
#define COLUMNS 4
using namespace std;

class cPreisach {
public:
    float input;
    float pdf[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    void load_array (){
    char c;
    float value=0;
    int getnum=0, rowno=0, columnno=0, power=0;
    bool decimalpoint=false, exponential=false;
    ifstream pdf_file (FILENAME);
    if (pdf_file.is_open()) {

  while (pdf_file.good()) {
    c=pdf_file.get();
    switch (c) {
      case '0': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10); if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=power*10; break;
      case '1': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+1; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+1; break;
      case '2': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+2; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+2; break; 
      case '3': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+3; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+3; break;
      case '4': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+4; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+4; break;
      case '5': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+5; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+5; break;
      case '6': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+6; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+6; break;
      case '7': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+7; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+7; break;
      case '8': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+8; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+8; break;
      case '9': if (exponential == false) {value = (value*10)+9; if (decimalpoint=true) getnum++;} else power=(power*10)+9; break;
      case '.': decimalpoint=true; break;
      case 'E': exponential = true; break;
      case ' ': if (value != 0){
                  value = value/(10^(getnum-power)); /*cout << rowno << columnno << "\n";*/ pdf[rowno][columnno] = value; value=0; power=0; getnum=0; decimalpoint=false; 
              exponential=false; columnno++;
            } break;
      case '\n': value = value/(10^(getnum-power)); /*cout << "newline" << rowno << columnno << "\n";*/ pdf[rowno][columnno] = value; value=0; power=0; getnum=0; decimalpoint=false; 
        exponential=false; rowno++; columnno=0; break;
    }
  }
  pdf_file.close();
}
}


void do_calculation (float input) {}
};

int main () {
  float input;
  cout << "welcome to the preisach function \n";
  cPreisach Preisach;
  cout << "created object, loading array \n";
  Preisach.load_array();
  cout << "please input magnetic field strength \n";
  cin >> input;
  Preisach.do_calculation (input);
  return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why cout could cause an access violation, but it must be something to do with the array, since if that function is commented out, cout is fine.

Thanks

EDIT since I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet: it was indeed a buffer overflow, partly because I was forgetting to increment from [0][0] instead of [1][1].  Don't know why it didn't occur to me; rather silly.  Thanks all :)

Comment: Are you sure you do not go outside the bounds of the array?

Comment: Why do you have 10 almost identical cases? Is there any reason you can't combine these?

Comment: Comment out case ' ' and case '\n'. If the program runs then your access violation most likely comes from pdf[rowno][columnno].

Comment: This seams like a very convoluted way of reading in exponential numbers from a file. It would be much easier to read in characters until you reach a space, then parse the string directly into a float.

Comment: Not related to the access violation, but `10^(getnum-power)` doesn't do what you want (it is a bitwise integer operation). Try `pow(10.0f, getnum-power)` instead.

Comment: `decimalpoint=true` is an assignment, so its value is always `true`. Use `if (decimalpoint)` (and `if (!exponential)`).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is caused at the access to the file. You should check if the file can be reached by the programm and that it is not courrupted.

Another thing I see is that you never open the file but check if it is open.

```
ifstream pdf_file (FILENAME); 
if (pdf_file.is_open()) {
```

That should look more like

```
ifstream pdf_file;
pdf_file.open(FILENAME);
if (pdf_file.is_open()) {
```

Surely the program can not read from the file if it is not yet opened and your if has to fail.

Comment: The constructor with a file name *does* call `open(FILENAME)`, so that part is ok.

Comment: I thought this is only true if `ios_base::openmode` is provided to the constructor too.